# Anything wrong with this simple Queue implementation?

Tags: c, queue

Assuming, arrays are ALWAYS contiguous,
I wonder if there is anything wrong with the QPop function now that iam doing memcpy ?

```
-- C snip ---------
    int Q[5];
    int QPush();
    static int pushIdx;
    int QPush (int *q, int val)
    {
        int ret=0;

        if ( isQFull(q) )
            return -1;

        q[pushIdx++] = val;
        return ret;
    }

    int QPop ( int *q)
    {
        int i, ret=0;
        unsigned long size = pushIdx -1 ;

        if ( isQEmpty(q) )
            return -1;

        ret = q[0];

        if ( size > 0 )
            memcpy ( q, q+1, (size*sizeof(int)) );

        q[pushIdx-1] = 0;
        pushIdx--;
        return ret;
    }

    int main()
    {
    QPush(&Q , 11);
    QPush(&Q , 12);
    QPush(&Q , 13);

    printf ( "pop = %d ", QPop(&Q));
    printf ( "pop = %d ", QPop(&Q));
    }
```

Thx.
-Nathan
It tested fine on all my condition [ platform latest Linux gcc ] so Iam looking for a case it might break.

Comment: Why not try to do a automated test, for example using CUnit?

Comment: Sounds like this question may be better suited for [codereview.se].

Comment: You for some inexplicable reason pass the queue around, but keep the top index as a global variable.

Comment: then, where can the index go ? C cannot have static members in typedef struct ? Iam trying to replace the  int Q[5];    with    typedef struct {
    int Event;
    int pushIdx;
}EventQ[5];
but in this case the index will be duplicated in each element which i dont like

Comment: You have it backwards. A queue consists of two things: (1) an index and (2) an array of elements. This means that your `struct EventQ` should contain two fields: an index `int pushIdx` and an array of elements `int Event[5]`. Nothing should be static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the manual of `memcpy()`, the memory areas must not overlap. But, *your* memory areas will. You should use `memmove()` for overlapping areas.